# How to express "used to be... but more a ... now"

Tags: word-usage

I want to write a sentence like "Gold, which used to be medium of exchange and unit of account in history, but now it is more the store of value and investment vehicle in financial markets". I don't know whether "it is more the ..." grammarly correct and has a clear meaning. If not, is there any way to improve it?

Comment: "...which used to be... but now is..." You don't need the _it_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `transform (verb)` in this context.

> transform
>
> *make a marked change in the form, nature, or appearance of.*

As for the example cited, it becomes "Gold transformed from a  medium of exchange and unit of account to a store of value and investment vehicle in financial markets"